# Tunneling through private OpenVPN on port 53

Tags: dns, openvpn, port, tunnel

To bypass restrictions of open HotSpots, I've created my own OpenVPN server in the cloud listening on port 53. I was able to successfully tunnel through it while I was on a tethered connection through my mobile phone.

In most WiFis I am encountering the following error though:

```
TLS Error: client->client or server->server connection attempted from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53
```

I am assuming the routers of those WiFis intercept DNS traffic and drop invalid packets or is there a configuration I could use to work around that?

Comment: Do you use UDP or TCP for OpenVPN? The default of UDP often causes such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS traffic on various ISPs and or Hotspots is often indeed often intercepted, so you can't rely on a random protocol (OpenVPN or others) to work just by pretending it is DNS.

Either pick a different port, or use some sort of tunnel that's built for IP over DNS, e.g. [iodine](https://code.kryo.se/iodine/).